# how to fire click event for the textbox

Tags: asp.net

how to fire click event for the textbox which is put under the gridview in item template in asp.net?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please give us a case scenario.

Comment: There is no "click" event for textboxes. Are you referring to some other event? You can fire a click event in javascript, but it doesn't exist within Asp.Net itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as making a clickevent outside a gridview. im using [jquery](http://jquery.com/)to do this

```
 <asp:textbox id="textbox1" ontextchanged="textbox1_textchange">
 <asp:linkbutton runat="server" id="hiddenbtn" onclick="textbox_click"/></asp:textbox>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#textbox1").click(function () {
    $('#hiddenbtn').trigger('click');
  });
});
</script>
```